# How to draw route from the server Android Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, server

I have a route on the server and i must show in my android application **exactly** this route.

Server Route
[image: Server route]
<sub>(source: [cs628731.vk.me](http://cs628731.vk.me/v628731040/6326e/vBMcyhFJ7zk.jpg))</sub>

In mobile must be exactly this route above between these markers(In this case it's not the same markers, but i hope you understood what i mean). Route lines must be in the same ways and same twists. All the path between same markers must be like server's route.
[image: Mobile route]
<sub>(source: [cs628731.vk.me](http://cs628731.vk.me/v628731040/63265/yBtioORw1ns.jpg))</sub>

**How to send this route to the application? By JSON or by KML or by XML?** Next, how to draw **identically** routes in my application(Google Maps)?

I have searched for the answer but it was unsuccessful. I hope, that somebody can show me example and help me.

Comment: I think your question needs a lot more info, like.. How are you retrieving the data from your server? In what form is it (json, etc.)? What do you mean by ***draw identically routes***? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: So to put it simply, you want to draw the routes on the google maps where the route values are retrieved from the server? Can you provide some test data? Like sample route source and destination?

Comment: If you mean two coordinates "start" and "end". Start 43.3241798855039, 76.95227196157317. End 43.31995220010836, 76.94835402553818. Or you want coordinates in each 20 meters for example from the server's route?